# UITableView is selecting cells by scrolling up and down

Tags: uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have a grouped table view in my iPhone application that contains a list of all 24 hours of the day. When the user selects one of the cells in the table view, it shows a checkmark in its accessory view and saves the data via NSUserDefaults. When the user loads the view going forward, this means that I have to pull the information out of the NSUserDefaults and display a checkmark on the corresponding cell. This works fine until I start scrolling in the view. Then this happens:

[image]

I've set my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` up such that when one row is selected, all the others are deselected. This works just fine, but by just scrolling through the list, seemingly random items start being selected. If I continue to scroll up and down a few times, all items will have been selected. If I click on one of the cells, that one cell is selected while the others' are deselected (which is the way it should be).

But how come the cells are selected just by scrolling? Here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, where the problem probably is located:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue;

    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cellValue = @"00:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        cellValue = @"01:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2) {
        cellValue = @"02:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 3) {
        cellValue = @"03:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 4) {
        cellValue = @"04:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        cellValue = @"05:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 6) {
        cellValue = @"06:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 7) {
        cellValue = @"07:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 8) {
        cellValue = @"08:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 9) {
        cellValue = @"09:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 10) {
        cellValue = @"10:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 11) {
        cellValue = @"11:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 12) {
        cellValue = @"12:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 13) {
        cellValue = @"13:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 14) {
        cellValue = @"14:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 15) {
        cellValue = @"15:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 16) {
        cellValue = @"16:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 17) {
        cellValue = @"17:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 18) {
        cellValue = @"18:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 19) {
        cellValue = @"19:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 20) {
        cellValue = @"20:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 21) {
        cellValue = @"21:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 22) {
        cellValue = @"22:00";
    } else if (indexPath.row == 23) {
        cellValue = @"23:00";
    }

    if ([[prefs valueForKey:@"quiet_hours_time_interval_from"] isEqualToString:cellValue]) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:72.0 / 255 green:104.0 / 255 blue:152.0 / 255 alpha:1];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
```

`prefs` is equal to `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` and I save the exact value of the (properly) selected cell to the `quiet_hours_time_interval_from` key.

Hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ELSE after your check for prefs valueForKey. You need to clear the accessoryType in that ELSE.

What you are seeing is the default behavior of the UITableView. Cells are cached, and only recreated when needed. That's what the bit at the top does with dequeueReusableCell.

So, since you don't have any code that ever clears the accessoryType, eventually all of them end up checked.